# postfix Peer certificate CN=`mint' did not match expected CN=`server.example.com'

Tags: linux-mint, postfix

postfix is complaining about it's cert?
I have no idea how to fix it...
It started out as a linux-mint distribution.
The cert must have been created by linux-mint, hench the name 'mint'.

Any help appreciated!

Edit: I was using php mailer with postfix.
When I add mint to the host file, it works, but I think every other email server rejected the email...

Edit2: basically, if I add '127.0.0.1 mint' into the host file, it work, but how do I fix the 'mint' cert and replace with a server cert for mail.example.com?

```
2023-06-23 04:09:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 server.example.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
2023-06-23 04:09:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO example.com
2023-06-23 04:09:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-server.example.com250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 10240000250-VRFY250-ETRN250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250-DSN250-SMTPUTF8250 CHUNKING
2023-06-23 04:09:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2023-06-23 04:09:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`mint' did not match expected CN=`server.example.com'
2023-06-23 04:09:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
```

```
Peer certificate CN=`mint' did not match expected CN=`server.example.com'
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L SE. Edit your question to include which command gave you that error. Also, post (sanitized) postfix config.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.